# Understanding tensorflow RNN encoder input for translation task

Tags: python, input, encoding, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm following this tutorial (https://theneuralperspective.com/2016/11/20/recurrent-neural-networks-rnn-part-3-encoder-decoder/) to implement a RNN using tensorflow.

I have prepared the input data for both encoder and decoder as described but I'm having trouble understanding how the dynamic_rnn function on tensorflow is expecting the input for this particular task so I'm going to describe the data I have for now in hopes someone has an idea.

I have 20 sentences in english and in french. As is described on the above link, each sentence is padded according to the longest sentence in each language and tokens for GO and EOS are added where expected.

Since not all the code is available on the link I tried doing some of the missing code for myself.  This is what my encoder code looks like

```
    with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:

        # Encoder RNN cell
        self.encoder_lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_units, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
        self.encoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([self.encoder_lstm_cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

        # Embed encoder RNN inputs
        with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
          embedding = tf.get_variable(
              "embedding", [self.vocab_size_en, hidden_units], dtype=data_type)
          self.embedded_encoder_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.encoder_inputs)

        # Outputs from encoder RNN
        self.encoder_outputs, self.encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            cell=self.encoder_cell,
            inputs=self.embedded_encoder_inputs,
            sequence_length=self.seq_lens_en, time_major=False, dtype=tf.float32)
```

My embeddings are of shape [20, 60, 60] but I think this is incorrect. If I look into the documentation for dynamic_rnn (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) then the inputs are expected to be of size [batch, max_time, ...]. If I look into this example here (https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/using-the-dynamicrnn-api-in-tensorflow-7237aba7f7ea#.4hrf7z1pd) then the inputs are supposed to be [batch, truncated_backprop_length, state_size].

The max length of a sentence for the encoder is 60.  This is where I am confused about what exactly should the 2 last numbers on the inputs should be. Should max_time be also the max length for my sentence sequence or should that be another quantity. Also should the last number be also the max length of the sentences' sequences or the length of the current input without the padding?